# WebTestClient mutate filter java.lang.IllegalStateException: No "WebTestClient-Request-Id" header

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to write unit tests for ExchangeFilterFunctions using WebTestClient, however am getting this error when mutating and adding a filter to the webTestClient.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No "WebTestClient-Request-Id" header

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WiretapConnector.lambda$connect$2(WiretapConnector.java:80)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1510)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:457)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek.subscribe(MonoPeek.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek.subscribe(MonoPeek.java:71)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:283)
    at com.ecs.springframework.reactive.web.filter.EcsMdcRequestExchangeFilterTest.whenExchangeFilterFunctionInjectedIntoWebTestClient_thenWebTestClientShouldIncludeHeader
```

The commented lines in the following test are added and result in the error above:

```
  @Test
  void whenExchangeFilterFunctionInjectedIntoWebTestClient_thenWebTestClientShouldIncludeHeader() {

    RouterFunction function =
        RouterFunctions.route(
            RequestPredicates.GET("/filter"), request -> ServerResponse.ok().build());

    WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(function)
        .build()
    //  .mutate()
    //  .filter(new AddHeaderExchangeFilter())
    //  .build()
        .get()
        .uri("/filter")
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk()
        .expectHeader()
        .valueMatches("FILTER-HEADER-KEY", "FILTER-HEADER-VALUE");
  }
```

AddHeaderExchangeFilter

```
public class AddHeaderExchangeFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

  @Override
  public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

    ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest
            .create(request.method(), request.url())
            .header("FILTER-HEADER-KEY", "FILTER-HEADER-VALUE")
            .build();

    return next.exchange(newRequest);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `AddHeaderExchangeFilter` you need to add the current request headers

```java
public class AddHeaderExchangeFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {

        @Override
        public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest request, ExchangeFunction next) {

            ClientRequest newRequest = ClientRequest.create(request.method(), request.url())
                                                    .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(request.headers()))
                                                    .header("FILTER-HEADER-KEY", "FILTER-HEADER-VALUE")
                                                    .build();
            return next.exchange(newRequest);
        }
    }
```

This is necessary for the `WebTestClient` correct behaviour and it verifying it when `exchange()` is executed.
In your filter you're creating a new request, and the header from the initial request is ignored, and not passed to `newRequest`.

---

**Side note:** I guess you tried to test that the filter is working, but your current test is not validating the header of the request, but the header of the response (so your test will fail).
My advice to you is to change your router to return the headers from the request

```java
RouterFunction function =
                RouterFunctions.route(
                        RequestPredicates.GET("/filter"), request ->
                            ServerResponse.ok().headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(request.headers().asHttpHeaders())).build()
                        );
```